# Installation of MySQL and WordPress on Kubernetes not connected to the database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, kubernetes

I used [this github repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.2/examples/mysql-wordpress-pd/) to create a Wordpess, but I have a question:

After the deployment, view logs wordPress tips are not connected to the database:

> [root@master k11]# kubectl logs wordpress WordPress not found in
>   /var/www/html - copying now... WARNING: /var/www/html is not empty -
>   press Ctrl+C now if this is an error!
>
> ```
> ls -A .htaccess
> sleep 10 Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
> ```
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10
>
> MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10

The docker-compose connection database has the Linx field, but there is no k8s below this field, how to find the hostname MySQL?

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
links:
- db:mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check wp-config file for proper Database name and user details